# type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

here in my code the problem with the consumer Auth, i found a similar q here but nor relevant with my error i tried to much ways to solve it, can anyone help please?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ProductProvider>(
            update: (ctx, auth, previousprod) => ProductProvider(
                auth.token, previousprod == null ? [] : previousprod.items),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: Cart(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: Order(),
          )
        ],
        child: Consumer<Auth>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'MyShop',
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
                accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                fontFamily: 'Lato'),
            home: auth.isAuth ? ProductOverviewScreen : AuthScreen(),
            routes: {
              // '/':(ctx)=> ProductOverviewScreen(),
              ProductDetailScreen.routName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
              CartScreen.routName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
              OrderScreen.routName: (ctx) => OrderScreen(),
              ProductOverviewScreen.routName: (ctx) => ProductOverviewScreen(),
              UserProductsScreen.routName: (ctx) => UserProductsScreen(),
              EditProductScreen.routName: (ctx) => EditProductScreen(),
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to construct `ProductOverviewScreen` in `home: ...`. It should be `ProductOverviewScreen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Believe this is the fix just copy paste and let me know :)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ProductProvider>(
            update: (ctx, auth, previousprod) => ProductProvider(
                auth.token, previousprod == null ? [] : previousprod.items),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: Cart(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: Order(),
          )
        ],
        child: Consumer<Auth>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'MyShop',
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
                accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                fontFamily: 'Lato'),
            home: auth.isAuth ? ProductOverviewScreen() : AuthScreen(),
            routes: {
              // '/':(ctx)=> ProductOverviewScreen(),
              ProductDetailScreen.routName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
              CartScreen.routName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
              OrderScreen.routName: (ctx) => OrderScreen(),
              ProductOverviewScreen.routName: (ctx) => ProductOverviewScreen(),
              UserProductsScreen.routName: (ctx) => UserProductsScreen(),
              EditProductScreen.routName: (ctx) => EditProductScreen(),
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it fixed it, the problem that i was forget to put () i realize after i posted the question  thanks for help too much i appreciate that

Comment: Hahaha cool homie :p glad it's all sorted now do that often not gonna lie :p